# Printing nothing in C

Tags: c

I am working on a C program that can store tasks that you need to do. Right now I am trying to make a grouping system that groups the tasks you need to do.

The program reads the "input.txt" file. You have to first write how many tasks you want to input and then the next lines are in this format. {**YYYYMMDD HHMM (Importance 1~10) (Group 0~4) (Title) (SubTitle)**}. For example like this : 20181101 0530 5 1 Computer coding.

But the problem is that now I need to list how many tasks are in each group in this format. {**(Tasks in group0) (group1) (group2) (group3) (group4)**}. So when there are **4 tasks** in group0, **2 tasks** in group 2, **1 task** in group 4, it prints out "**4 0 2 0 1**".

The code I was working on :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 struct Tasks{
    int date;
    int time;
    int i;
    int group;
    char title[127];
    char sub[127];
 };

struct Groups{
    int gr0;
    int gr1;
    int gr2;
    int gr3;
    int gr4;
};
int main(){
    FILE *file;
    int num;
    int j;
    struct Tasks task[num];
    struct Groups group;

file = fopen("input.txt", "r+");

fscanf(file, "%d", &num);

rewind(file);

for(j=0;j<num;j++){
    fscanf(file, "%d %d %d %d %s %s\n",
           &task[j].date, &task[j].time, &task[j].i, &task[j].group,
           &task[j].title, &task[j].sub);
}

for(j=0;j<num;j++){
    switch(task[j].group){
        case 0:
            group.gr0 = group.gr0 + 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            group.gr1 = group.gr1 + 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            group.gr2 = group.gr2 + 1;
            break;
        case 3:
            group.gr3 = group.gr3 + 1;
            break;
        case 4:
            group.gr4 = group.gr4 + 1;
            break; 
    }
}
printf("%d %d %d %d %d",
       group.gr0, group.gr1, group.gr2,
       group.gr3, group.gr4);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `struct Groups group;` ==> `struct Groups group = {0};`

Comment: What is the problem with the code you show us? Please elaborate. And please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: A hint to *one* possible problem: Uninitialized local variables really *are* uninitialized, and they will have an *indeterminate* (and seemingly random) value. Now think about that and how you use e.g. `num` before it's initialized...

Comment: And *another* problem is that you don't check what [`fscanf` *returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value) so you won't know about errors. And you ***will*** get an error reading your file since for some reason you *rewind* the file to its start and read the the value for `num` *again*.

Comment: Oh my gosh, thanks so much!!!

Comment: Can someone post an actual answer here please?

Comment: 1. Why [`fopen(..., "r+");`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen)? The `+` enables writing but I don't see any attempt to write into this file. Better "r" in this case. 2. Immediately after `fscanf(file, "%d", &num);` follows `rewind(file);` [`rewind()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/rewind) _Moves the file position indicator to the beginning of the given file stream._ This looks like `num` would've the same value like `task[0].date`. Is this intended? (Hard to believe.)

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the first number in the file into `num` and then attempting to read input this number of times. To me, this looks as if your input starts with the number of items present, and then lists each item.

However, you're calling `rewind()` one you have read the value of `num` and then go on to read the input. As you probably know, `rewind()` takes you back to the beginning of the file. This means that at the point where you are trying to read the first item, you're actually reading the *number of items* as well as the first item, and your input processing will be thrown off course.

You probably need to remove the `rewind()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Reworked the code a bit and commented changes. Should work, probably still has some holes...

BTW, you should not use VLAs. They are optional after C99 and cannot relied upon being available.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

struct Tasks{
    int date;
    int time;
    int i;
    int group;
    char title[127];
    char sub[127];
 };

struct Groups{
    int gr0;
    int gr1;
    int gr2;
    int gr3;
    int gr4;
};

int main(){
    FILE *file;
    int num;
    int j;
    //RO access
    file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if(!file){
        perror("");
        return 1;
        }

    fscanf(file, "%d", &num);

    struct Tasks task[num];
    //Init the struct so you dont have random garbage values
    struct Groups group = {0};

//Need to move that up so you get a valid content for num in your task definition.
//file = fopen("input.txt", "r+");
//fscanf(file, "%d", &num);

// Can't rewind, you will be reading num again
//rewind(file);

for(j=0;j<num;j++){
//Last two arguments automatically decay to a pointer, & is wrong.
if(6 !=  fscanf(file, "%d %d %d %d %s %s\n", &task[j].date, &task[j].time, &task[j].i, &task[j].group, task[j].title, task[j].sub)){
    printf("Error on reading file!\n");
    fclose(file);
    return 1;
    }
}

//Don't forget to close it
fclose(file);

for(j=0;j<num;j++){
    switch(task[j].group){
        case 0:
            group.gr0 = group.gr0 + 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            group.gr1 = group.gr1 + 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            group.gr2 = group.gr2 + 1;
            break;
        case 3:
            group.gr3 = group.gr3 + 1;
            break;
        case 4:
            group.gr4 = group.gr4 + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d", group.gr0, group.gr1, group.gr2, group.gr3, group.gr4);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your program you need not required to add `rewind()`function.As the value of `num` is the first element in file, rest of the file contains the data regarding groups and tasks.

```
     #include <stdio.h>

    #include <string.h>

`   #include <stdlib.h`>

    #include <errno.h>

    struct Tasks{
        int date;
        int time;
        int i;
        int group;
        char title[127];
        char sub[127];
     };

    struct Groups{
        int gr0;
        int gr1;
        int gr2;
        int gr3;
        int gr4;
    };

    int main(){
        FILE *file;
        int num;
        int j;

        file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
        if(!file){
            perror("");
            return 1;
            }

        fscanf(file, "%d", &num);

        struct Tasks task[num];

        struct Groups group = {0}; 


    //scanning rest of the file (from line 2 on wards)
    for(j=0;j<num;j++){                

    fscanf(file, "%d %d %d %d %s %s\n", &task[j].date, &task[j].time, &task[j].i, &task[j].group, task[j].title, task[j].sub);//

    }


    fclose(file);

    for(j=0;j<num;j++){
        switch(task[j].group){
            case 0:
                group.gr0 = group.gr0 + 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                group.gr1 = group.gr1 + 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                group.gr2 = group.gr2 + 1;
                break;
            case 3:
                group.gr3 = group.gr3 + 1;
                break;
            case 4:
                group.gr4 = group.gr4 + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("%d %d %d %d %d", group.gr0, group.gr1, group.gr2, group.gr3, group.gr4);
     return 0;
    }
input.txt contains
```

[input.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoqJa.png)

and the output is

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIB9N.png)